# Why are asserts commented out in Linkedlist.java source code

Tags: java

I have been looking into linkedlist.java, sun's source code. It does a good job of adding asserts in private function. The Effective java clearly states even private functions should be validated.
What remains unclear is why are all asserts commented out in Linkelist code ?

Here is a quick link: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html

Thanks,

Comment: I think that's because `assert` should be used only while developing. Code shouldn't be released with `assert`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Why ? In a production environment, they're not even active.

Comment: It's potentially a premature optimization. The person commenting out the asserts may not have been aware that they will not trigger in production code.

Comment: I've voted to close as "opinion based". Unless a Sun/Oracle developer enters the conversation, I think we'll be guessing here.

Comment: Their [first introduction](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/diff/6d24852165ba/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) already have those `assert`s commented out. So we have no answers here.

Comment: @LachlanEaston Maybe but... in Java's standard LinkedList ? I would expect the commiters here to be a little more aware...

Comment: Asserts are disabled unless you run with `-ea` flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must be a mistake.

As assertions have no cost in a production environment (see [Enabling and Disabling Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable)), there's no reason to comment them when switching from development to public release.

When an assertion appears, for any reason, to be useless, then it should be totally removed before public release, not commented out.

There may be many practical reasons (I won't list hypothesis) having made a developer comment them at one time, but those comments should not have found their way into released code.